# Alerting users after the first 10 minutes of every hour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to alert users when clicking on a button after the 10th minute of every hour. I tried the following code without success :

```
function alert10() {
    var today = new Date().getHours().getMinutes();
    if (today > 10) {
        alert("You can only access this section within the first 10 minutes of every hour");
    } 
}

<li><a href="{{route('sel.sec')}}" onclick="alert10()">Section</a></li>
```

Comment: this is something i would rarely advise to do in javascript frontend code.

Comment: whats wrong with setInterval()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getHours()` gets the hours, `getMinutes()` gets the minutes into the current hour. It doesn't make sense to chain those. (For instance, at 4:25, it's saying "4.getMinutes()" but 4 is not an object with such a method.)

All you need is to remove `getHours()` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **SetInterval** after 10 minutes each hour

**setInterval**(yourFunction, 1000 * 60 * 10);